# XAML ComboBox set selected item from ListBox does not work properly

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox, listbox

I have a list of objects. I want to maintain their properties with a text box and a combo box. The list of objects is presented in a list box. When selecting an object its properties are displayed in the text box and combo box. The problem is that if I select an item in the combo box it is displayed but it no longer changes when selecting an object from the list box. 
Partial MainPage.xaml

```c#
  <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20,20,0,0"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding TypNamnLista}"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding Obj.Typnamn, Mode=OneWay}}"
                  />             <!--Same behavior for Mode=TwoWay-->
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20,20,0,0" Background="{ThemeResource ListBoxBackgroundThemeBrush}" Foreground="Black" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListBoxBorderThemeBrush}"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding ObjList}"
                 SelectionMode="Multiple"
                 SelectionChanged="ListBox1_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                  <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Namn}"/>
                  </StackPanel>
             </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Partial MainPage.cs

```c#
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private ObservableDictionary defaultViewModel = new ObservableDictionary();

        public Obj obj { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Obj> ObjList { get; set; }
        public List<string> TypNamnLista { get; set; }

        public ObservableDictionary DefaultViewModel
        {
            get { return this.defaultViewModel; }
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.ObjList = new ObservableCollection<Obj>();
            for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
            {
                Obj o = new Obj(); o.Namn = "Obj" + i; o.Typnamn = "Typ" + i;
                ObjList.Add(o);
            }
            obj = new Obj();
            this.DefaultViewModel["Obj"] = obj;
            this.DefaultViewModel["ObjList"] = ObjList;
            this.TypNamnLista = new List<string> { "Typ1", "Typ2", "Typ3" };
            this.DefaultViewModel["TypNamnLista"] = TypNamnLista;
            //DataContext = this; (set in XAML)
        }

        private void ListBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Obj v = (Obj)e.AddedItems[0];
            Debug.WriteLine("ListBox1_SelectionChanged: Namn=" + v.Namn + ", Typnamn=" + v.Typnamn);
            obj.Namn = v.Namn;
            obj.Typnamn = v.Typnamn;

            ((ListBox)sender).SelectedItems.RemoveAt(0); // Requires <ListView SelectionMode="Multiple"
        }

    }
}
```

Class Obj has the interface INotifyPropertyChanged and code to trigger the bindings Obj.Namn and Obj.Typnamn in the XAML. The binding Obj.Namn works all the time but the binding Obj.Typnamn stops working when the combo box item has been selected from the UI.  
When debugging the app and selecting an object in the list box I observe that after the PropertyChanged methods in Obj are called the Immediate Window displays the following message four times. When running without Debug no errors appear.

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

I would be grateful for help to find the fault in my code or another approach to maintain a list of objects where one property is bound to one of a very limited number of strings.

Comment: Could you attach a sample project.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this again and found that it works when changing the XAML for the combo box from

> SelectedValue="{Binding Obj.Typnamn, Mode=OneWay}"

to

> SelectedValue="{Binding Obj.Typnamn, Mode=TwoWay}"

contrary to what I stated in the question. I apologize for the unnecessary question.